Where did they get facehuggers from?
One of the great selling points of Alien: Romulus is continuing the story from the original movies featuring Ellen Ripley as the main character, especially from the first two ones: Alien (1979) and Aliens (1986). "Romulus" takes place somewhere after the first "Alien", as in the first few minutes of the movie, we can see the debris created by the explosion of (USCSS) Nostromo and remnants of its additional passenger.
But here is the thing: The second movie (followed by the subsequent ones, as well as other media) quite precisely specified the reproduction cycle of xenomorphs:
The queen lays eggs, and from those eggs hatch "facehuggers" looking for a live host. After impregnating the host, the "facehugger" dies while the larval stage of the xenomorph explodes from the body of its carrier.
There are some nuances here and there, like suggestions that under the right circumstances, a simple drone/warrior can become a queen etc.
So after recovering the alien from the remains of Nostromo, the crew of the Romulus-Remus station would have only one adult "warrior/drone"

which was killed near the resting place of the android Rook - notice that this is still a regular warrior.

But when the Rain Carradine and her friends board the derelict of the station, they are met with defrosting facehuggers, as seen in the trailer:



How did the station get them in the first place from a single warrior?

Special offer on Shein. You will get some people forcibly impregnated with an alien foetus that will kill its host, but at these prices you’d be crazy not to!

Rook and the other characters in the film referred to the Facehuggers as parasitoids.

ROOK: The parasitoid has implanted the Plagiarus praepotens in her.
ANDY: I beg your pardon?
ROOK: A seed that will amalgamate with her DNA and rapidly grow out of her.

Around an hour and 11 minutes into the film, Rook states that the parasitoids were bioengineered from the DNA of the 1979 film's Xenomorph -- AKA the 'Big Chap' -- which was retrieved from space in the opening scene of Alien: Romulus.

ROOK: Inside the parasitoids I bioengineered from the Xenomorph's DNA, I discovered a unique, non-Newtonian fluid. Life in its most primal, unadulterated form.

Around 36 minutes into the film, there's a shot of a computer screen displaying the following information:

SPECIMENS COMPLETED: 36
PRINTING PAUSED


The camera then pans over to a static 3D printer that has partially printed a Facehugger within some type of membrane.



Following that, there's a shot of dozens of Facehuggers (all within similar membranes) in cold storage.



So apparently, Rook was able to 3D print Facehuggers, based on DNA extracted from the Big Chap.

I must have missed that line! So it is down to a handwaved science rather than getting facehuggers from another source.

Kinda lends credence to my head canon that the black goo is a terraforming tool, and the xenomorph is a form-of-last-resort survival mechanism for it.

+1 to this comprehensive answer, though I must add that "[...] a unique, non-Newtonian fluid. Life in its most primal, unadulterated form" takes the cake as one of the dumbest, most nonsensical cringeworthy sentences in modern cinema facepalm.

@Moo "Black goo", in which piece of fanfiction did they describe it? Such a shame they never made more than two Alien movies ;)
